# How to do QR Factorisation of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given A = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 3\\2 & -6 & 3\\ -2 & 3 & -3\end{bmatrix}$

How would i find the QR factorisation? Well i have a guide on how to do this and have attempted several times but failing to get the correct answer, could someone please explain simply how to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Depends. You can do Gram-Schmidt, or you can use Givens or Householder matrices. Maybe you should edit your question to mention these attempts you speak of.

Comment: It's difficult to explain what you're doing wrong if you don't show your work!

Comment: im using the QR Algorithm!

Comment: The "QR algorithm" is inappropriate, since it's used for computing eigenvalues...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To find $Q$ and $R$, follow the following steps

1) Use Gram-Schmidt technique to get an orthonormal set of vectors $\left\{ u_1, u_2, u_3\right\}$ which are the columns of $Q$ from the set of the columns of $A$ $\left\{ c_1, c_2, c_3\right\}$.

2) To find $R$, simply compute $Q^{-1}A$, since $A=QR$. Note that, $Q^{-1}=Q^{T}$.

Comment: is that the QR algorithm? im not sure it is meant to be gram smitdz although i am confused...

Comment: I believe you are asked to find $Q$ and $R$ and just follow the hint I already gave you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Givens rotation: Doing so you make zeros appear in you original matrix.

Your final Q is going to be a product between all the rotation that you have use to make zeros appear.

Comment: While the mention of Givens rotations is apt, in posting an answer to a question asked so long ago (2 years), a brief response is not as helpful as would be a more detailed one that improves on the previous responses.  Pointing out the specific improvements will also be of assistance to Readers.